# PHP - get array value if next element is not series

Tags: php, arrays

Here is my array

```
$array = array( 0 => 10, 1 => 9, 2 => 8, 3 => 6, 4=> 4 );
```

I want to get array value 6. because, 7 is missing before this value/series is break.

Please help me how can I do it easy & fast method.

Comment: What do you need?

Comment: I want to get array value '6' from this array.

Comment: `echo($array[4]);`

Comment: Have you tried a loop?

Comment: I doesn't want to get value by key. I want to get value if next array value is not serialized. If you notice this array, you can see that after array value '6', 7 is missing in this value. So, I want to get array value 6

Comment: Please see my updated answer. It returns the first and stops the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sequence could be calculated by subtracting the first value from the second value. Then you could for example use a `for` loop to loop through the values of the array and check if there is also a next value available by checking if there is an index + 1.

Then if that is the case you can subtract the current value in the loop from the next value and check if that result equals the step size.

If that is not the case, the next value of the iteration is the value that breaks the sequence and you can break out of the loop.

```
$array = [10,9,8,6,4];

if (count($array) > 2) {
    $step = $array[0] - $array[1];
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
        if (isset($array[$i + 1]) && $array[$i] - $array[$i + 1] !== $step) {
            $wrongValue = $array[$i + 1];
            echo sprintf(" The step count is %d, but after %d comes %d which breaks the sequence.",
                $step, $array[$i], $wrongValue
            );
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/CEqrM)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you want to achieve, but let's start it here.

UPDATED:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); ++$i) {
  if($i > 0) {
    if($array[$i] != ($array[$i-1]-1)) {
      echo($array[$i]);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
6
```

Comment: I want to get array value not want to check if array value is '6'

Answer (score 0):

Loop through it, save the previous values and compare with current one:

```
<?php
function findMissing($array) {
  $missing = [];
  foreach($array as $key => $val) {
    if(isset($previousValue) && $previousValue-1!=$val) {
        echo "not in series: ".($previousValue-1) .", returning ".$val."<br>\n";
        $missing[] = $val;
    }
    $previousValue=$val;
  }
  return $missing;
}

// USAGE:

$array = array( 0 => 10, 1 => 9, 2 => 8, 3 => 6, 4=> 4 );

findMissing($array);
// not in series: 7, returning 6
// not in series: 5, returning 4

$array2 = array( 10, 9, 8, 6, 5 );

$missingValues = findMissing($array2);
// not in series: 7, returning 6

var_dump($missingValues);
// array(1) { [0]=> int(6) }
```

Comment: It gives 6 & 4. Does it possible to get only 6. Which array key if firstly

Comment: Yeah, you've changed your array. See the input array here. 5 is missing.

Comment: I've added 2 examples, also with your new array. Finds only '6'.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$sequence =
[
    0 => 10,
    1 => 9,
    3 => 8,
    4 => 6,
    5 => 4
];

$last = null;
foreach($sequence as $k => $v)
{
    if(!is_null($last) && $last - $v > 1)
        break;
    $last = $v;
}
var_dump($k, $v);
```

Output:

```
int(4)
int(6)
```

Comment: Does it possible to get only '6'? Because 6 is less than 4 by array key.

Comment: If you don't care about keys, ignore them.